# How do i change theme/colors of bootstrap template without sass or scss?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a resume website for someone using a start bootstrap template but the color is not good(poop color). how can i change it? when i go to youtube, all the videos say to use sass and download packages. i did that but it just messes up the site. i dont think the site was meant to do that or im not doing it right. is there a easier way?

i tried to use sass but it is not working or i am not doing it right. Is there a way to change the css of the template. I just want the theme color different

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861601/changing-the-primary-bootstrap-color-without-scss

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use SASS to change the CSS of Bootstrap sites. Just use normal CSS, but ensure that:

a) Your CSS must be the most specific

> E.G.  IF bootstrap's CSS is `.someclass` then yours could be something like `section.grandParentClass #parentContainerID .someclass` - in other words, providing a more complete DOM reference to the desired element(s)

b) Your CSS must come after the Bootstrap CSS

> If there are two conflicting CSS instructions, the last one wins.  For example:
>
> `.someClass {color: blue;}`
> `.someClass {color: red;}`
>
> The color of the element will be red.

Of course, it will never be that obvious, so you must pay attention and figure out where to place your CSS so that it is the last CSS (for that element) that the browser sees before rendering the DOM.

However, something like changing an entire theme all-at-once is asking too much. For that, it is easiest to install NodeJS and SASS and figure all of that out. **The point of this answer is that you can almost always use normal CSS for most of your desired changes.**